# simple user login form - yii framwork

Tags: php, yii, widget, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am trying to open a login form on my site. I have written code but some how it's not working.

The problem is that the login form does not return any error or mesage, it only redirects me to the login page.

Also, for some reason the `checklogin` function is not working.

controller/main:

```
public function actionLogin()
  {
  $model = new LoginForm;
  $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
  }
```

model/LoginForm:

```
    class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
  public $email;
  public $password;

  private $_identity;

  public function rules()
  {
    return array(
      array('email, password', 'required', 'message' => 'error'),
      array('email', 'email', 'allowEmpty' => false, 'checkMX' => true, 'message' => 'error'),
      array('password', 'authenticate')
    );
  }

  public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
  {
    $this->_identity = Account::model()->checkLogin($this->email, $this->password);
    if(!$this->_identity)
            $this->addError('password', 'error');
  }

}
```

model/account:

```
    public static function model()
  {
    return parent::model(__CLASS__);
  }

  public function tableName()
  {
    return 'table';
  }

  public function primaryKey()
  {
    return 'id';
  }

  public function checkLogin($email, md5($password))
  {
    $user = $this->findByAttributes(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password));
    if($user===null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    return false;
```

views/main/login:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('login'))); ?>
    <table>
      <tr><?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?></tr>
      <tr> <?php echo $form->emailField($model,'email'); ?></tr>
      <tr><?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?></tr>
      <tr><?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?></tr>
    </table>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: is there any error you are getting, any debugging you have done?

Answer (score 2):

To implement your authentication you must follow the steps below:

First in your action:

```
public function actionLogin() {
    $model = new LoginForm();
    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
        if (CActiveForm::validate($model) && $model->validate() && $model->login()) {
            // Authentication DONE
        } else {
            //TRY TO GET ERRORS
        }
    }
}
```

In your model add the login function:

```
public function login() {
    /*
     * if identity property had no value, here we initialize 
     * identity property
     */
    if ($this->identity === null) {
        $this->identity = new UserIdentity($this->username, $this->password);
        //authenticating
        $this->identity->authenticate();
    } else {
        /*
         * if error code was NONE, it means user has been successfully
         * authenticated.
         */
        if ($this->identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
            Yii::app()->user->login($this->identity);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and in your model's authentication method:

```
public function authenticate() {
    //if validation was done and we had no error while validating
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        //new instance of identity class
        $this->identity = new UserIdentity($this->username, $this->password);
        if (!$this->identity->authenticate()) {
            $this->addError('password', Yii::t('app', 'Invalid Username or Password'));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to add UserIdentity Class (Put this class in your components directory)

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity { 

private $_id;
private $_username;

public function authenticate() {
    $record = Account::model()->findByAttributes(array(
        'username' => $this->username
    ));

    if ($record === null) {
        //adds error to user
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        //authentication failed
        return false;
    } else if (!CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($this->password, $record->password)) {
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        return false;
    } else {
        /*
         * no error
         * user information[username and password are valid]
         */
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;

        //user's id whitch will be accessible through Yii::app()->user->id
        $this->_id = $record->id;
        //user's username whitch will be accessible through Yii::app()->user->name
        $this->_username = $record->username;
        //success
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Overriding CUserIdentity's getId() method
 * @access public
 * @return integer user id
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->_id;
}

/**
 * Overriding CUserIdentity's getName() method
 * @access public
 * @return string username
 */
public function getName() {
    return $this->_username;
}
```

Comment: Almost there. How are you passing the user login details to the model?

Comment: @YaakovSwissa do you render your page?

Comment: @crafter when your form has been submitted, forms data will be passed into model, where you say: $model=new LoginForm();

Comment: OK. because the model is of CFormModel. I missed that, as I'm mostly working with CActiveRecord models. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Change checklogin function as given below and try again to fix this.

```
public function checkLogin($email, md5($password))
  {
    $user = $this->model()->findByAttributes(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password));
    if($user===null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

If you are trying to implement the login functionality separately, then you are missing the whole logic to register the user's auth details using the `Yii::app()->login()`dependent on the CUserIdentity class.

Master this link -> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth and proceed for post authentication.